# Unable to decompress by Snappy in Python

Tags: python, unicode, snappy

In my project I am using [Snappy](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy/blob/master/test_snappy.py) compression in HTML pages in Python. I am successfully compressing the HTML pages. `html_page` contains the html string of the website.

```
import json
import snappy
state_dict["html_page"] = unicode(snappy.compress(html_page),errors="ignore")
"""
If i miss this unicode function 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 0:    unexpected code byte

"""
........
........
return json.dumps(state_dict)
```

But I am facing the problem in uncompressing the compressed data:

```
d = json.loads(mydict)
snappy.uncompress(d['html_page'].encode("utf-8"))

In [122]: snappy.uncompress(d['html_page'].encode("utf-8"))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UncompressError                           Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/gridlex/workspace/MatrixInfrastructure/<ipython console> in <module>()

UncompressError: An error ocurred while uncompressing the string
```

Can you help me out in Snappy compression and decompression? Or which is the optimal way to compress and decompress for transferring the data over the network?

Comment: What exactly fails if you leave out the call to unicode? I'd assume snappy returns a byte string and json.dumps produces a byte string as well, there should not be any decoding going on.

Comment: snappy return ISO-8859-2 encoded I have checked with "chardet"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> state_dict['test'] = snappy.compress('random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, random string with ö, ')
>>> dump = json.dumps(state_dict, encoding='ISO-8859-2')
>>> load = json.loads(dump, encoding='ISO-8859-2')
>>> snappy.uncompress(load['test'].encode('ISO-8859-2'))
```